# Row_Number() to partition by last character of value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to use a row number to partition a dataset by two columns. But only partition it by the last character of the value in the given column.

Lets say I use the folllowing query:

```
SELECT ColumnA,
       ColumnB,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA, ColumnB ORDER BY ColumnA, ColumnB) RN
FROM Table1
```

ColumnB contains values in the following range: 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000. I want it to partition Column B only by the last character of the values (in the above example '0')

Is this possible and how would I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps ... right(ColumnB,1)

Comment: ... Or `(ColumnB % 10)`, if it's an integer column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ColumnB` is varchar, you can use `RIGHT()`:

```
SELECT ColumnA,
       ColumnB,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RIGHT(ColumnB, 1) ORDER BY ColumnA, ColumnB) RN
FROM Table1
```

Otherwise, you can use `% 10` to obtain the last digit.

Comment: can't believe i didn't think of that myself. Thanks so much. Works perfectly!